# How can I sort by _geo_distance in NEST for Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Is it possible to sort by `_geo_distance` with the NEST library for Elastic Search? I can't find any support for it.

The raw json for doing what I want is:

```
"sort": [
      {
         "_geo_distance": {
            "position": {
               "lat": 59.3389428,
               "lon": 18.0761637
            },
            "order": "asc",
            "unit": "m",
            "distance_type": "plane"
         }
      }
   ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var results = client.Search<object>(sd => sd
    .SortGeoDistance(d => d
        .OnField("position")
        .Unit(GeoUnit.Miles)
        .DistanceType(GeoDistance.Plane)
        .PinTo(Lat: 59.3389428, Lon: 18.0761637)
        .Ascending());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var search2 = _client.Search < Person > (s => s
  .Sort(s => s
    .GeoDistance(g => g
      .Field("location1")
      .Order(SortOrder.Ascending)
      .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Plane)
      .Points(search1.Geocoord)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Great that you took your tome to answer, but it is better to also add an explanation to your code.